# Include external Razor Helper Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

Is there a way to import a razor in-line helper in the view?

I tried the following:

```
<% Html.Partial("PaginationTemplate"); %>

<!-- later down -->

<%= KnockoutPagination("pendingQuestionsPagination", "$root.pendingQuestionsViewModel.pagination") %>
```

Inside PaginationTemplate.cshtml...

```
@helper KnockoutPagination(string id, string context) {
<div id="@id" class="pagination pagination-centered" data-bind="with: @context, visible: @(context).hasPages">
    <ul>
        <li data-bind="css: prevCss"><a href="#" data-bind="click: clickPrev">Prev</a></li>
        <!-- ko foreach: pages -->
        <li data-bind="css: $parent.pagingItemCss($data)"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.changePage"></a></li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <li data-bind="css: nextCss"><a href="#" data-bind="click: clickNext">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a global helper instead, which can be referred to anywhere.  If you add an app_code folder, put a CSHTML file in there and define the helper, you can refer to this global helper by doing:

```
<file name>.<helper name>(params)
```

Then you can refer to it wherever you want.  [See this for more information](https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/asp-net/how-to-store-razor-helpers-globally/).

Comment: Can I all this razor helper from an ASPX page?

Comment: You can call a global helper from any ASPX or CSHTML page (depending on your template), but aren't you using Razor, and mean CSHTML?

Comment: well, I am trying to use Razor moving forward, but in the mean time, I need to support aspx views.

Comment: I would have thought the functionality matched, but I can't find an example of helpers using ASPX templates.  So I would say that helpers aren't supported if the `<% helper %>` syntax isn't supported.  That would mean your only option of getting what you are trying to do is to use a Partial view.

Comment: @MladenB.Thanks for the update - updated the resource.